# How to use `cor.test` for correlation of specific columns?

Tags: r, correlation

I have the following data example:

```
A<-rnorm(100)
B<-rnorm(100)
C<-rnorm(100)

v1<-as.numeric(c(1:100))
v2<-as.numeric(c(2:101))
v3<-as.numeric(c(3:102))
v2[50]<-NA
v3[60]<-NA
v3[61]<-NA

df<-data.frame(A,B,C,v1,v2,v3)
```

As you can see df has 1 NA in column 5, and 2 NA's in column 6.
Now I would like to make a correlation matrix of col1 and 3 on the one hand, and col2,4,5,6 on the other. Using the cor function in R:

```
cor(df[ , c(1,3)], df[ , c(2,4,5,6)], use="complete.obs")

#             B         v1         v2         v3
# A -0.007565203 -0.2985090 -0.2985090 -0.2985090
# C  0.032485874  0.1043763  0.1043763  0.1043763
```

This works. I however wanted to have both estimate and p.value and therefore I switch to cor.test.

```
cor.test(df[ ,c(1,3)], df[ , c(2,4,5,6)], na.action = "na.exclude")$estimate
```

This does not work as *'x' and 'y' must have the same length*. 
This error actually occurs with or without NA's in the data. It seems that cor.test does not understand (unlike cor) the request to correlate specific columns. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: `cor.test` says `x` and `y` should be vectors. One alternate option is  `corr.test` from `psych` package

Comment: Thank you, this looks excellent! There seems even a possibility for Benjamini Hochberg inside, nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer` to perform the test between all pairs of columns. Here `X` and `Y` are data frames expanded from `df`, consisting of 8 columns each.

```
outer(df[, c(1,3)], df[, c(2,4,5,6)], function(X, Y){
    mapply(function(...) cor.test(..., na.action = "na.exclude")$estimate,
           X, Y)
})
```

You even get output on the same form as `cor`:

```
           B          v1          v2          v3
A 0.07844426  0.01829566  0.01931412  0.01528329
C 0.11487140 -0.14827859 -0.14900301 -0.15534569
```

Comment: You're welcome! `outer` is a great function, but beware that `X` and `Y` can get very big if you use it on large data sets.